# How to Debug (step-by-step) Ionic 5 Capacitor App on iOS Simulator/Device on an iMac in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, debugging, visual-studio-code, capacitor, ionic5

I am building an ionic 5 capacitor app on visual code (latest) on an iMac and would like to do a step-by-step debug of my app on an iOS simulator or device in visual code. So far I could NOT find a way to do this on visual code.

There was an alternative with web inspector on Safari. But this option is extremely confusing to find the right code file and right code line as the debug needs to happen wrt transpiled code on Safari dev tool editor rather than the typescript code I created in visual studio code.

I'd like to know if there is any better way to debug my typescript code line by line in Visual Code for the ionic capacitor app while running it on iOS simulator or device on an iMac.

Appreciate your support/pointers in achieving the above.

Comment: There is an extension for CORDOVA debugging in vscode, called vscode-cordova. Sadly, it does not work with capacitor and no adjustment has been made to this day.